# Cannot view Python OpenCV recorded video

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am doing a minor research project for my Master's Degree and don't have much experience with programming, but I need to record myself juggling and then track the balls. Unfortunately, I am having trouble at the first stage. This is the code I am using to record

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/Users/Sean/Videos/output1.avi', -1, 30.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using -1 for the fourcc to choose my own codec (Intel IYUV). I am using a Logitech C920 camera for this. If I record a very short video (~30 seconds) I can watch the video and open it in opencv with no issues. When I record longer videos, I cannot open the file. I have tried watching it in Windows Media Player which shows me that the first ~6 minutes of a 10 minute video is a multi-colored screen with shadows of me juggling in the background. The last 4 minutes is fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where did you store the data?, are trying to create a temp or maybe will store to specific database. Are you referring to this link for your reference? - http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: I'm saving it into my Videos folder. I have also tried recording using the default recording software installed on my computer. In that case, the recording is fine, but I cannot open the video in OpenCV. Is that a codec issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you have time try to explore this, hope it would help..

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:/Users/Sean/Video/soutput.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```